# Azure DevOps cancel build using C# library

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have C# code that is using the Microsoft.TeamFoundation NuGet packages for interacting with Azure DevOps. I am trying to cancel any build that are currently running for a particular branch. There isn't a CancelBuild method, but some web pages have indicated using the UpdateBuild method to achieve this. I am using the code below, but it returns an error "Bad Request" with no further details.

```
var builds = await buildClient.GetBuildsAsync(Guid.Parse(Settings.ProjectId), new List<int> { buildDefinitionId }, statusFilter: BuildStatus.InProgress);

var buildsToCancel = builds.Where(x => Helpers.GetBranchName(x) == branchName).ToList();

foreach (var build in buildsToCancel)
{
   build.Status = BuildStatus.Cancelling;
   await buildClient.UpdateBuildAsync(build);
}
```

How do I cancel a build using this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared the complete code of your app. Based on your requirement, here is the sample for your reference, which works for me to cancel the builds for `testBranch` from my pipeline with the Id of `10062`.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CancelBuildsFromBranch
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Replace with your Azure DevOps organization URL and personal access token
            string organizationUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/xxOrgNamexx";
            string personalAccessToken = "xxxxxxxxxx";

            // Create a connection
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(organizationUrl), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));

            // Get the build client
            BuildHttpClient buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

            // Replace with your team project and build definition id
            string teamProject = "TheProjectName";
            int buildDefinitionId = 10062; // your-build-definition-id

            // Get the builds for the specific definition
            List<Build> builds = await buildClient.GetBuildsAsync(teamProject, new[] { buildDefinitionId });

            // Filter the builds for those from the 'testBranch'
            List<Build> buildsFromTestBranch = builds.Where(b => b.SourceBranch == "refs/heads/testBranch").ToList();
 
            // Cancel the builds from 'testBranch'
            foreach (Build build in buildsFromTestBranch)
            {
                if (build.Status == BuildStatus.InProgress || build.Status == BuildStatus.NotStarted)
                {
                    build.Status = BuildStatus.Cancelling;
                    await buildClient.UpdateBuildAsync(build, teamProject, build.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled build {build.Id} from 'testBranch'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope the information could help.

Comment: That works, but annoyingly that overload is marked for deprecation. However, when I use the overload it recommends it returns the "Bad Request". So, I'm using the deprecated method and hopefully it will be fixed before they remove it. The warning is: BuildHttpClientCompatBase.UpdateBuildAsync(Build, string, int, object, CancellationToken)' is obsolete: 'Use UpdateBuildAsync(Build, bool, object, CancellationToken) instead.